# How to arrange numbers in Label into grid in Tkinter?

Tags: python, grid, tkinter, label, sudoku

I create a sudoku solver and I want to show candidates for each cell. Sudoku grid is list of Label widgets and I have a problem with arranging these candidates into grid. My goal is something like [this](https://imageshack.us/scaled/large/94/sudokuja.png) (without colors). I already have them in grid, but number "0" is still visible. And I´m asking you how to hide these zeros. I tried to substitute "0" with space (" "), but brackets are displayed instead.

My code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text_good = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
text_wrong1 = [1,2,3,4,0,0,0,8,9]
text_wrong2 = [1,2,3,4," "," "," ",8,9]

L1 = Label(root,bg="red",text=text_good,wraplength=30)
L1.place(x=0,y=0,width=50,height=50)

L2 = Label(root,bg="red",text=text_wrong1,wraplength=30)
L2.place(x=50,y=0,width=50,height=50)

L3 = Label(root,bg="red",text=text_wrong2,wraplength=30)
L3.place(x=100,y=0,width=50,height=50)

root.mainloop()
```

I hope I described my problem well. I appreciate any answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text_wrong2 = ' '.join(map(str,[1,2,3,4," "," "," ",8,9]))` instead of passing directly the list as the text option. Remember that the default font is not monospaced, so the numbers won't be aligned as in the other two examples.

Apart from that, I recommend you to use `grid` instead of `place`, and represent each number using a `Label`, instead of using only one for each cell and relying on the new lines that are added because of the width. Thus, you don't have to worry about handling the offsets for each label.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text_good = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
text_wrong1 = [1,2,3,4,0,0,0,8,9]
text_wrong2 = [1,2,3,4," "," "," ",8,9]

def create_box(text_list, **grid_options):
    frame = Frame(root, bg="red")
    for i, text in enumerate(text_list):
        Label(frame, text=text, bg="red").grid(row=i//3, column=i%3)
    frame.grid(**grid_options)

create_box(text_good, row=0, column=0, padx=10)
create_box(text_wrong1, row=0, column=1, padx=10)
create_box(text_wrong2, row=0, column=2, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This isn´t completely right. Zeros are hidden, which is surely positive, but number four should be right under 1. 8 should be right under 2 etc. This is the main problem. To you `grid` note.

I used `grid` once, but I was not capable of set size of `Label` in pixels. It always was dependent on font size, which is quite inconvenient. That´s the only reason why I use `place` instead.

Comment: @MilanSkála That is what I meant by _"The default font is not monospaced, so the numbers won't be aligned as in the other two examples"_. In fact, one of the problems of your code is that it relies on the font size, that is why I suggested another geometry manager. I have updated my answer so you can see a solution using `grid`.